# I am trying to write a program that allows me to input multiple integers, but it won't allow me to enter in my set of integers

Tags: java, arrays, sum, int

My code won't allow me to enter in multiple integers to where it can then compute the sum, the count of integers, the minimum, and the sum of positive even integers. I am not sure if I need another method or if im calling for the wrong things.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment2 {
private static final Scanner input = null;
private static int n;

public static void main(String[] args){


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum=0, minNumber=0, nCount=0, countEvenIntegers=0;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = sc.nextInt();


    //when code reads 0, code terminates
     int[] numbers = new int[4];
     for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
         numbers[i] =sc.nextInt();

     }

     while(!(n==0)){
           sum += n;
           n = input.nextInt();
        }

    class SumOfValues {
        public int sum(int...vals){
            int sum=0;
            for (int val : vals) {
                sum+= val;
            }
            return sum;
        }

    }
    class CountingInts{
        public void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            int count=0;
            System.out.print("Numbers: ");
            while (input.hasNextInt()){
                input.nextInt();
                count++;
            }
            System.out.print(count);
            input.close();
        }
    }


    int sumPositive = 0;
    System.out.println("The minimum integer is " + minNumber +  "\nThe count of integers is " 
    + nCount + "\nThe sum of positive integers is " + sumPositive + "\nThe count of even integers in the sequence is " + 
            countEvenIntegers );


}




}
```

Comment: *How* won't your code allow you to enter multiple integers? Can you please elaborate on the problem you have? Do you get compiler errors? Run-time errors or exceptions? Wrong output? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am allowed to enter in integers, however it gives me 0 for each outputs

Comment: No, it doesn't. This code doesn't compile. So it can't run. Read the compilation error, and fix it.

Comment: I renamed my second variable "i" and now when it allows me to run the program, but it doesn't output anything

Comment: when i remove     
  //when code reads 0, code terminates
      int[] numbers = new int[4];
      for(int i1=0; i1<4; i1++){
       numbers[i1] =sc.nextInt();
      
      }
        it reads The minimum integer is 0
The count of integers is 0
The sum of positive integers is 0
The count of even integers in the sequence is 0, but won't output any number other than 0

Comment: Why do you expect to get any other result? You are not doing any operations on anything. And your classes `SumOfValues` and `CountingInts` are not used. And why would you even have them as classes? Make them methods and for god sake, remove the second `main` method

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are an absolute beginner, so I'd recommend not dealing with functions and classes and all that, and just write everything linearly. I'm not sure why you have all those functions, classes and variables, but to help you, this is probably the simplest way to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0, minNumber = 0, nCount = 0, countEvenIntegers = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            int input = sc.nextInt();

            if (input == 0) {
                break;
            }

            sum += input;
            nCount += 1;
        }

        System.out.println("The minimum integer is " + minNumber);
        System.out.println("The count of integers is " + nCount);
        System.out.println("The sum of positive integers is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The count of even integers in the sequence is " + countEvenIntegers);
    }
}
```

Note that I've not added the minimum interger and count of even intergers for you to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are doing in your code since you are not doing any operations on the variables you are outputting, and thus should not expect the output to be any other than 0.

Also, your inner classes are really weird.

Here is an example (based on your code) that does what you want. Plenty of ways of achieving your goal, but I think this is simple enough:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment2{

private static final Scanner input = null;
private static int n;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum=0, minNumber=0, nCount=0, countEvenIntegers=0, sumPositive = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(true) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();

            if(i == 0) {
                break;
            }

            numbers.add(i);
        }
        if(numbers.size() > 0) {
            minNumber = numbers.get(0);
        }

        for (int number : numbers) {
            sum += number;
            if(minNumber > number) {
                minNumber = number;
            }
            if(number % 2 == 0) {
                countEvenIntegers++;
            }
            if(number > 0 ) {
                sumPositive += number;
            }
        }

        nCount = numbers.size();

        System.out.println("The minimum integer is " + minNumber +  "\nThe count of integers is " 
        + nCount + "\nThe sum of positive integers is " + sumPositive + "\nThe count of even integers in the sequence is " + 
                countEvenIntegers + "\nThe total sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried doing the code posted above but got this as an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Assignment2.main(Assignment2.java:33)

Comment: @TaylorColeman I cannot recreate the NullPointerException you are describing. I did however encounter a IndexOutOfBounds when I do `minNumber = numbers.get(0);` and fixed it by making a check before doing that.